# CSS menu with individual images for first li level and on li:hover

Tags: css

I'm working on a css menu. I'm trying to edit existing code and I need to do a css menu with individual images for every item of the first level `<li>` like so:

```
.leftmenu a.link1 { padding-top: 42px; background:transparent url('../images/home_on.gif');   }
.leftmenu a.link2 { background:transparent url('../images/serv_off.gif'); }
.leftmenu a.link3 { background:transparent url('../images/know_off.gif'); }
.leftmenu a.link4 { background:transparent url('../images/exp_off.gif'); }
.leftmenu a.link5 { background:transparent url('../images/ref_off.gif'); }
.leftmenu a.link6 { background:transparent url('../images/links_off.gif'); }
.leftmenu a.link7 { background:transparent url('../images/contact_off.gif'); }
.leftmenu a.link8 { background:transparent url('../images/blog_off.gif'); }

.leftmenu a.link1:hover { background:transparent url('../images/home_on.gif') -163px -42px no-repeat; background-position:0 0; }
.leftmenu a.link2:hover { background:transparent url('../images/serv_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat;   background-position:0 0;  }
.leftmenu a.link3:hover {background:transparent url('../images/know_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat; background-position:0 0; }
.leftmenu a.link4:hover { background:transparent url('../images/exp_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat; background-position:0 0; }
.leftmenu a.link5:hover { background:transparent url('../images/ref_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat; background-position:0 0;  }
.leftmenu a.link6:hover { background:transparent url('../images/links_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat; background-position:0 0;  }
.leftmenu a.link7:hover {background:transparent url('../images/contact_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat; background-position:0 0;  }
.leftmenu a.link8:hover {background:transparent url('../images/blog_on.gif') -163px -28px  no-repeat; background-position:0 0;  }
```

Now I'm trying to add a flyout to this menu and the only way I could find to do it was like this:

```
li.list2:hover + ul.sub-menu{  
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 14px;
text-indent: 0px!important;

background-color: black;
margin: 0px;

list-style: none;
top: -20px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
ul.sub-menu{
display: none;
}
```

There is also this css being added to the menu:

```
.leftmenu{ width:163px; margin-left:7px; position: relative; z-index: 0;}
.leftmenu ul{ margin:0px; padding:0px;  }
.leftmenu  a { display:block; width:163px; height:0; padding-top:28px; color: white;  text-indent:-3000px; }
```

This seems to be working ok except that when I roll off the menu item set to display the sub-menu items the sub menu simply disappears, maybe it's a z-index issue but I don't think so?

I don't mind even recoding it from scratch I maybe in jQuery if someone can point me in the direction of a nice tutorial to style each of the first menu items individual colors/images.

Comment: just add the link properly via the menu in the editor and the link will get a nofollow attribute (if you are worried about google indexing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either because you have a gap between the first level menu and the sub menu item OR your 'nested ul' is not nested within the li causing the hover behaviour.

You definitely have the latter issue i.e.

```
<ul>
  <li/>
  <li>
    <a/>      <<< (read below first) in here...
  </li>
  <ul />     <<< this ul should be (see above arrows)
  <li/>
</ul>
```

Comment: A gap where??? I just can't see it... in the html? in the css?
Thanks for the edit i didn't realise it would add a no follow :D
If's it's a physical gap your talking about then I have tried overlapping the menu and it still disappears as soon as i scroll of the upper menu item...

Comment: You don't have a gap (though this is a common problem in :hover based css menus) you have an unusual / broken structure

Comment: thank you I've been so F***ing stupid, such an easy fix and I was in capable of seeing it! 
Thank you for taking the time to take a look Paul. your a star.
I had the nesting wrong i had just used what was there allready without checking through it.. my bad i suppose don't trust ugly code!!!!!
Yon wouldn't believe how many different css pseudo selectors i used just to get it to show on hover :nth-child/+/> LOL 
It now works exactly as it should do. simple :hover .sub-menu{ and there it is!!!

Comment: No worries - I believe its called getting code blind. If a problem persists take a break for a while or get some fresh eyes :)